# How does a Checkout Page take the user input information and pass it to Stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment, checkout

So far I've created a product modal and upon proceeding to checkout, Stripe popup appears and the user can proceed with the payment.

https://streamable.com/30p4eh

Although, I have to change the checkout button to popup a checkout page first so the user can enter his delivery address and so on. How does a checkout page deliver the information the user has input, into Stripe? How does the whole process work? Do I have to add all my products into Stripe product page? Can Stripes checkout page be used like in this Firebase video? [Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XKRxeo9414&t=370s)

Comment: Hi @carrianne could you be more specific about what you need to know? And add any code you've already tried?

Comment: the items the user wish to purchase have to be passed into the checkout page where he/she inserts his personal data and delivery address. The payment goes through Stripe and Stripe delivers the Items purchased by the User with Webhooks back to the Sales Point to process it. Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure about the webhooks but the rest is right. Then you can redirect/handle the returned data however you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checkout [payments guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment) now includes a nice diagram that I think should help understand what you're asking about.

You create a Checkout Session with the payment information and then redirect your customer to Stripe. Stripe displays the information about the purchase and collects payment information from your customer, then redirects them back to the URL you specify. In the background, you're notified about the success of the payment and you can manage order fulfillment.

If you need more information about a particular piece of this, please feel free to ask with more details!

Update: on a second review, I see that I missed that your video is showing the Legacy Checkout integration. Stripe has a new Checkout integration that supports a wide range of payment methods and supports SCA-compliant authentication challenges. Take a look at the [migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) to update your integration.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for this! Do you know if there is a specific video tutorial for this?

Comment: There are a couple :)  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VQ5jccnZ2Ow&feature=youtu.be